# QGIS crashing when editing layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have a plugin that creates a new layer, which works fine. 
When I edit this layer using the QGIS GUI, and done editing, I get the question of if I like to save the layer. If I hit 'yes' (and I want to save the changes), QGIS crashes (`QGIS died on signal 11ptrace: Operation not permitted.`)

I suspect this has someting to do when I create the layer:

```py
layer = QgsVectorLayer("point", "test_points", "memory")
provider = layer.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField("ID", QVariant.Int),
        QgsField("TYPE", QVariant.String),
        QgsField("lat",  QVariant.Double),
        QgsField("lon", QVariant.Double)])

layer.updateFields()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
layer.editingStarted.connect(self.ayer_edit)
layer.editingStopped.connect(self.layer_edit_end)
```

What do I miss?

EDIT:
I suspect this behavior has to do with my creation of layers. I tried to open and create a layer from a ESRI shape. The layers displays correctly, but when editing and saving the changes, QGis craches.

Comment: Did you removed the last two lines? They seems unrelated to your new "in memory" layer `layer` or you does not show us enough code. Why do you use connect on `self.static_layer.editingStarted` and `self.static_layer.editingStopped` whereas I would expect `layer.editingStarted` and `layer.editingStopped` instead ?

Comment: @ThomasG77 I did simplified the code for this post, it was originally part of a class. Sorry about that. I edited it now

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: @GermánCarrillo I am using 3.12. I also had this issue using 3.10, so I tried to update.